# Java IO Exception Catching

Tags: java, exception

I need my application to bring up an error in writing to the location [`/dev/full`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/full). Is there anyway I can do this with Java exception handling? I am already throwing and catching IOerrors, so I don't know what the problem is...?

I am reading data from standard in, and compressing it and writing it to standard out.

Writing to /dev/full isn't raising an exception...any ideas on how to raise an exception for this?

Comment: You need your application to bring up an error. You are throwing exception, but you are also catching it. What do you exactly?

Comment: I catch the error and print a stack trace, and exit with nonzero status. I am reading data from standard in, and compressing it and writing it to standard out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Parent Class for all Exceptions that is `Exception`. If you are not sure which type of exceptions are thrown from `try` block, use `Exception` in your last catch block.

something like this

```
try{
   ....//code here
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
    log(fnfe);
}
catch(IOException ioe){
    log(ioe);
}
catch(Exception e){
    log(e);
}
finally{
  ....//code here
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, I need to ouput and error when writing to  /dev/full. Its not coming up as an IOexception, any ideas?

Comment: if you are able to open and write to a file sucessfully, you will not get IOException. You need to throw custom exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a code for writing all the details of the error and any specific comments you wish to make regarding the class or object so that you can trace the error better inside the catch block.

```
try
{
//Your code
}
catch(SomeException e)
{
//Create a file, write data to it and close it.
}
```

I use this technique to save user data in case a file cannot be opened for modifications. Helps because i am sure that the data will be stored at either of the 2 places.

Also, this doesn't  affect my further executing of the program as the data is loaded in an object of `File`. 
There could be better methods to the above. But this is what my professor showed me. Could be of use.

Comment: I have updated my question, I need to ouput and error when writing to  /dev/full. Its not coming up as an IOexception, any ideas?